# Why not let users install application on sdcard

Tags: android

I know that we can specifically let users install an Android application on their sd cards through the Android Manifest.

Is there a good reason not to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if you have seen the documentation on this very issue of [App Install Location](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) - Specifically, the document gives this warning: **Warning**: When the user enables USB mass storage to share files with a computer or unmounts the SD card via the system settings, **the external storage is unmounted from the device and all applications running on the external storage are immediately killed.**.